# Redirecionamento Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em **Codeigniter 3** na empresa onde trabalho e preciso substituir uma antiga. A situação é que o endereço url será alterado porém não podemos desativar de vez o anterior, será feito o redirecionamento de quem entrar através do link anterior deverá redirecionar para o novo e temos artigos como os de um blog. Por exemplo:
**http://domain.com.br/blog/artigos/1** preciso que quando receber este url, seja redirecionado para **http://novodomain.com.br/artigos/1**

Estava tentando fazer isto pelo codeigniter através do routes.php, porém sem sucesso.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Tente colocar a URL no config do projeto antigo:
Ex:

```
$config['base_url'] = ' http://novodomain.com.br';
```

Quando o usuário acessar a URL antiga, ele redireciona para o novo.